# Looping through and clearing arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have arrays within arrays, all with varying amounts of information. My CSV table currently has the fields Name, Email, and  Phone Number. 
Below is my array;

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Email
        [2] => Phone Number
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Mick
        [1] => mick@mick.com
        [2] => 01234 324234
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => james
        [1] => james@james.com
        [2] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => reg
        [1] => reg@reg.com
        [2] => 10293 467289
    )

)
```

I wish to loop through and remove these null values and combine the Email and Phone Number into Info end up with an array which resembles

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Info

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Mick
        [1] => mick@mick.com + 01234 324234
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => james
        [1] => james@james.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => reg
        [1] => reg@reg.com + 10293 467289
    )

)
```

Here is my current script, I am recienving the error;

```
<b>Warning</b>:  array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in <b>C:\Users\Lydia\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\CSV.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

every time that I loop through the changeRow() function, any help greatly appreciated

index.php

```
<?php
include 'CSV.php';
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$file = read_csv('Book1.csv');

$input = changeRow($file);
```

CSV.php
....
....

```
    function changeRow($rows){

    $len = count($rows);

    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){

        $rows = array_filter($rows[0],0);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `array_map()` instead of `foreach()`. Example:

```
$file = read_csv('Book1.csv');
$input = array_map(function($v){
    $phone = (isset($v[2]) && $v[2]) ? ' + '. $v[2] : '';
    return array($v[0], $phone);
},$file );
if(isset($result[0][1])) $result[0][1] = 'Info';

print '<pre>';
print_r($input);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide two methods that output the requested array structure. ([PHP Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/scmaB))  These methods iterate the array, check if the iteration is dealing with the "column heading" subarray or not, then conditionally appending the value from subarray element `[2]` to subarray element `[1]` using `+` as glue.

Method #1: `foreach()`

```
foreach($array as $index=>$item){
    if(!$index){
        $result[]=['Name','Info'];
    }else{
        $result[]=[$item[0],$item[1].(strlen($item[2])?" + $item[2]":'')];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Method #2 `array_map()`

```
var_export(
    array_map(function($index,$item){
        if(!$index){
            return ['Name','Info'];
        }else{
            return [$item[0],$item[1].(strlen($item[2])?" + $item[2]":'')];
        }
    },array_keys($array),$array)
);
```

Output: (from either method)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Name',
    1 => 'Info',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Mick',
    1 => 'mick@mick.com + 01234 324234',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'james',
    1 => 'james@james.com',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'reg',
    1 => 'reg@reg.com + 10293 467289',
  ),
)
```

ps. If you want to remove the `$index==0` check that is iterated each time, you can manually overwrite the first subarray after the loop is finished like this: ([PHP Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/WoVMn))  *this just means you will be "writing" data to the first subarray twice.

```
foreach($array as $item){
    $result[]=[$item[0],$item[1].(strlen($item[2])?" + $item[2]":'')];
}
$result[0]=['Name','Info'];
var_export($result);
```

or

```
$result=array_map(function($item){return [$item[0],$item[1].(strlen($item[2])?" + $item[2]":'')];},$array);
$result[0]=['Name','Info'];
var_export($result);
```

pps. "[Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)" *can* be used for this task, but I've elected not to use `&$array` because it can risk causing trouble "downscript" and many developers advise against using it until other methods are inadequate.  Here is what that can look like: ([PHP Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/Ke3M0))

```
foreach($array as &$item){
    if(strlen($item[2])) $item[1].=" + $item[2]";
    unset($item[2]);
}
$array[0]=['Name','Info'];
var_export($array);
unset($item);  // var_export($item); // ($item = NULL)
```

Comment: @JoeSmith if my answer satisfies, please award it the green tick so that this page can be used to close new duplicate questions.  (the other answer had multiple errors/issues so this page could not be used as a pre-existing reference.